# How do I include Hanami into the existing Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hanami

Is that possible to use Hanami as a engine in the Rails application? I didn't found any straight-forward way to do this in the docs so far.

Comment: Have you tried to mount the applications side by side in `config.ru`?